# Getting "Cannot query module due to -mod=vendor(Go version in go.mod is at least 1.14 and vendor directory exists.)" error when executing unit test

Tags: go, testing

I'm new to the Go language. I'm trying to run a unit test using the `go test` command, but the below error shows up:

```
cannot query module due to -mod=vendor
        (Go version in go.mod is at least 1.14 and vendor directory exists.)
```

I then tried to run `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor` in sequence, and after that the unit test worked fine.

What is the root cause of the error? What happened when I executed `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor`? Why does executing those two commands help resolve the problem?

Comment: If `tidy` and `vendor` fix the problem, that means you were missing something from your vendor directory.

Comment: Stop vendoring.

Comment: I wish "stop vendoring" were an option, but some companies require vendoring as a policy.